# Image path concatenation is possible for react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**I write the code below,**

```
 source={require(`../../assets/images/${post.image}`)}
```

**in this {post.image} have dynamic values, its something like an array - img1.png,img2.png likewise**

**How to concatenate this path and values.
It's working on react but it's not working on react-native, How to solve that issue ?**

Answer (score 0):

In react native you can't have dynamic resources with require. Check React Native docs for solution:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources

you can't use variable in require. You can store your resource in an constant like

```
const img1 = '../../assets/images/img1.png'

<Image source={require(img1)} />
```

Or string constant directly

```
<Image source={require('../../assets/images/img1.png')} />
```

Comment: You where close,
<Image
  source={{ uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png' }}
  style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
/>

Comment: @roel can you help me to solve this issue

Comment: @Azzy can you help me to solve that issue

Comment: @Azzy I can't handle the situation

Comment: @roel I can't match may problem with documentation,can you help me to solve it?

Comment: @ChamakaMendis updated answer with example

Comment: @roel can we store more images like the array in const img1 and we can display those images separately using the map method?

Comment: @ChamakaMendis yes of course, that's the common practice

Answer (score 0):

documentation link was provided in the answer by @role

in the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#images-from-hybrid-apps-resources) for images in assets folder

```
  assets
     -app_icon.png
```

use the `asset:/` scheme

```
 <Image
  source={{ uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png' }}
  style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}  // Also you have to specify image dimensions manually
 />
```

if that does not work then create a dictionary of image components